# Adding Firebase/Messaging CocoaPod causes iOS app to not build

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The iOS app worked fine before adding Firebase/Messaging, but after adding it and running 'pod update' I started getting these errors when building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from: 
objc-class-ref in FirebaseMessaging(GIPReachability_d54098c5c1e1fdc4fca31a4803478650.o) 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my current Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'KarmaSous' do
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.1.4'
  pod "GMStepper"
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
      end
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `pod 'Firebase/Messaging'` instead of `pod 'FirebaseMessaging'`?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, and I have solved the error.

Please make sure that "Edit Scheme > Build > Build Options > Find Implicit Dependencies" is checked.

[image]